# Prolog not giving correct answer

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I am learning Prolog. I wrote some simple facts. But it seems that Prolog is not giving me right answers. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

`facts` -   weather.pl

```
weather(pheonix,summer,hot).   
weather(pheonix,winter,warm).  
weather(la,summer,warm).
```

When I run this in swi-prolog as follows

```
?- weather(City,_,warm).
City = pheonix .
```

Result is only shown as `pheonix`. But `la` is also `warm`. Why is it not given as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, after first answer is written, you can type some key, usually ";", to backtrack and receive another answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the answer very, very closely:

```
City = pheonix .
              ^ SPACE!
```

There is a space between the answer substitution and the dot. This little hint tells us: You have stopped asking for further answers. Try the query again and this time type SPACE or `;` but do not type RETURN, for it will again stop the answers.